# How do I reverse this formula

Tags: polynomials

How do I get $a$, $b$, and $c$
given

$$X=\frac{a+\frac{1}2b}{a+b+c}$$

$$Y=\frac{b(\frac{\sqrt3}{2})}{a+b+c}$$

$$Z=\frac{76a+150b+29c}{255}$$

in other words How do i get $a$, $b$, and $c$ on the left side using these three formulas?

Comment: I think you don't. We cannot solve explicitly for $a,b,c$ in terms of $X$ and $Y$ alone, three variables $a,b,c$, two equations only.

Comment: I added a third equation. Will it work now?

Comment: Yes, it will work now, except perhaps for very peculiar values of $X,Y,Z$ that produce a zero denominator when we do the solving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As André Nicolas commented, in the rhs, there are three unknowns $(a,b,c)$ but you only have two equations.

If you fix one of these $(a,b,c)$, you can reverse the formulas. Suppose for example that you select a value for $a$; in such a case, you will have (assuming no problem with the denominator) $$b=\frac{2 a Y}{\sqrt{3} X-Y}$$ $$c=\frac{a \left(\sqrt{3}-2 Y\right)}{\sqrt{3} X-Y}-a$$ If you prefer to fix $b$ or $c$, the same priciple would apply.

Comment: I like Claude Leibovici's answer. I knew this would happen. Can I have all six answers in the same way? If I had B, or C as well?

Comment: Yes, it is the same way : select two as variables and you have two equations for two unknowns. If you slect $b$, you have $a=\frac{b \left(\sqrt{3} X-Y\right)}{2 Y}$ and $c=-\frac{b \left(\sqrt{3} X+Y-\sqrt{3}\right)}{2 Y}$. I let you doing the third case. Cheers :-)

Comment: Ok Thank you. It's for mapping a colorspace, If you wanted to know for color matching. ABC would be RGB and any matching values should be matches in color but not luminescence and brightness. IE the same amount of weighted color primaries.